# How to get PHP to send mail to local users (cakePHP, Linux SLES)

Tags: php, cakephp

Currently I have a mail server configured (a real one from my ISP) and mail internal and external works on the command line.  In PHP only external users work.

For testing I would like to send to internal users only.

( Ideally I would like to set up lots of aliases that point to one user so mail to:
tom@localhost.com, dick@localhost.com, harry@localhost.com end up in /var/mail/johnsmith )

I'd be greatful if someone could help here.  I'm hesitant to edit the postfix config files...

On the command line johnsmith@localhost works but not in PHP.  It's using cakePHP and I checked the value of $email-addr just before the send ($this->Email->send();) and the value is johnsmith@localhost.  I'm not that familiar with cakePHP yet. The var/log/mail shows nothing, only external email addresses.

(server is Suse linux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In /etc/postfix/main.cf add localhost.com:

```
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain,localhost,localhost.com
```

This allows sending on "localuser@localhost.com" via command line.  I loaded up a test php mail form script in a browser and it works, sending mail through to /var/mail/localuser.

At the moment it means I have to check each local users /var/mail file.  I'm working on the alias. My first attempt at that failed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the basic mail php function

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Under linux, mail php function relies on sendmail, just check that sendmail is properly installed.